# Обработка массива

Tags: массивы, php, классы

Есть класс для работы с массивами

```
class arr {
  var $data;

  public function __construct($array){
    $this->data = $array;
  }

  public function get($name){
    return $this->data[$name];
  }
}
```

Его работа:

```
$_test = new arr(array(
  'name' => '  <123'
));
```

А вот теперь вот что, возможно ли заставить его работать ещё и так?

```
echo $_test->get('name')->trim();
```

т.е. если после get() ничего нет, то он возвращает элемент массива, иначе он отдает результат следующему методу, и т.д. и в конце концов возвращается обработанная строка, например:

```
echo $_test->get('name')->trim()->replace('<', '')->toInt();
```

Comment: Совет читать учебники просвистел мимо ушей, ага... Но на всякий случай контрольный вопрос: метод `get()` возвращает значение какого типа?

Comment: Блин, честно, до сих пор не пойму, зачем нести в PHP jquery-style...

Неужели вам так действительно удобней работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без претензий на абсолютную истину (и с полным непониманием зачем такой код вообще нужен):

```
class _string
{
  public function __construct($string)
  {
    $this->string = $string;
  }

  public function __toString()
  {
    return $this->string;
  }

  public function trim()
  {
    $this->string = trim( $this->string );
    return $this;
  }

  public function replace( $what, $to )
  {
    $this->string = str_replace( $what, $to, $this->string );
    return $this;
  }
}

/* ------------------------------------------ */
class arr
{
  public function __construct($array)
  {
    $this->data = $array;
  }

  public function get($name)
  {
    return new _string($this->data[$name]);
  }
}

/* ------------------------------------------ */
$arr = new arr(array('name' => '  <123'));
print (string)$arr->get('name')->trim()->replace( '<', '' );
print "\n";
print (int)(string)$arr->get('name')->trim()->replace( '<', '' );

/* ------------------------------------------ */
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы использовать цепочки вызовов таким образом как вы хотите необходимо чтобы каждый из элементов массива был объектом.

Например:

```
class Name {
    private $name;
    private $value;

    public function __construct($name, $value){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function trim() {
        $this->value = trim($this->value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function toInt() {
        $this->value = (int)$this->value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

class Names {
    var $data;

    public function __construct($array){
       foreach($array as $name => $value) {
           $this->data[] = new Name($name, $value);
       }
    }

    public function get($name){
        foreach ($this->data as $item) {
            if ($item->name == $name) {
                return $item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Теперь используем цепочку вызовов:

```
$names = new Names([
    'Eva'    => ' Mendes 35',
    'Pamela' => ' Anderson 40' 
]);

echo $names->get('Eva')->trim()->toInt();
```

P.S Код еще нужно дорабатывать в некоторых местах. Но думаю суть реализации такого функционала будет понятна.

Comment: Синхрон :)